# Get all Nodes from a List of adjacent LineStrings in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql

I use PostGis and pgRouting.
I have a table with geometries of the adjacent edges returned by a shortest path query. I want to concatenate these edges and retrieve a list of all nodes these edges consist of. How do I do this in SQL?

I think the solution would be a mix of LineMerge and GeomUnion, but is there a smart way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: ST_LineMerge won't do the job.

ST_LineMerge — Returns a (set of) LineString(s) formed by sewing together a MULTILINESTRING.

PGRouting send you back a list of linestring. Maybe GemUnion is the key. I'll check that if I can.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I did it myself with that sql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION adjacent_linestring_array_to_set_of_points(array_geom geometry[])
   RETURNS SETOF geometry AS
$$
DECLARE
    accu_line geometry;
    temp_line geometry;
BEGIN

FOR temp_line in select * from unnest(array_geom) LOOP
    IF accu_line is NULL THEN
        accu_line := temp_line;
    END IF;
    accu_line := linemerge(GeomUnion(accu_line, temp_line));
END LOOP;

RETURN QUERY SELECT ST_PointN(accu_line, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(accu_line)));
END;
$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT;
```